# How can I use SHFileOperation in C#?

Tags: c#, directory

I'm trying to move a folder from directory to another directory , but I'm getting an exception of `access to path is denied` , so I found a c++ SHFileOperation method that can be used in this case, the problem is that I didn't have any idea how to use it:

```
        public void MoveFolder(string oldPath,string newPath)
        {
           SHFILEOPSTRUCT hFILEOPSTRUCT = new SHFILEOPSTRUCT();
           hFILEOPSTRUCT.pFrom = oldPath;
           hFILEOPSTRUCT.pTo = newPath;
           int res = SHFileOperation(ref hFILEOPSTRUCT);
        }

        [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, 
        ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        [Obsolete]
        static extern int SHFileOperation(ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT lpFileOp);
```

Struct definition of SHFILEOPSTRUCT:

```
    [Obsolete("Use this element with caution and only if you know what you are doing. It's only meant to be used internally by MahApps.Metro and Fluent.Ribbon. Breaking changes might occur anytime without prior warning.")]
    public struct SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public FO wFunc;
        public string pFrom;
        public string pTo;
        [CLSCompliant(false)]
        public FOF fFlags;
        public int fAnyOperationsAborted;
        public IntPtr hNameMappings;
        public string lpszProgressTitle;
    }
}
```

This code throw an exception

> Cannot marshal field 'fAnyOperationsAborted' of type 'ControlzEx.Standard.SHFILEOPSTRUCT': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int32/UInt32 must be paired with I4, U4, or Error).

How can I make this works?

Comment: Can you show us your struct definition for `SHFILEOPSTRUCT`?

Comment: It's imported from this package `ControlzEx.Standard` , I've updated my question.

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SHFILEOPSTRUCT.html and http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHFileOperation.html